# Parsing with Lex and Yacc (Simple Calculator)

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I am new to Lex & Yacc programming and just getting started with grammar. I cam across this program on the net and have been trying to understand it. Following are the Lex and Yacc code-snippets for a simple calculator :

**Lex rule**:

```
%% 
[a-z]       {
                 yylval = *yytext - 'a';
                 return VARIABLE;
             }
[0-9]+      {
                 yylval = atoi(yytext);
                 return INTEGER;
             }
[-+()=/*\n] { return *yytext; }

[ \t]      ;
.               yyerror("invalid character");
%%
```

**YACC grammar**:

```
%%  
program:
         program statement '\n'
         |
         ;

statement:
         expr                      { printf("%d\n", $1); }
         | VARIABLE '=' expr       { sym[$1] = $3; }
         ;  

expr:
         INTEGER
         | VARIABLE                { $$ = sym[$1]; }
         | expr '+' expr           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
         | expr '-' expr           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
         | expr '*' expr           { $$ = $1 * $3; }
         | expr '/' expr           { $$ = $1 / $3; }
         | '(' expr ')'            { $$ = $2; }
         ;
%%
```

Can anyone please help me understand step by step how the input expression `x = 3 + 4` will be processed/parsed ?

As per my understanding, while processing the input, '`x`' will return **VARIABLE** whereas `3`, `5` and `4` will be returned as **INTEGER** by Lex. However, in Yacc, as per the grammar, since a VARIABLE could be deduced as expr, the expression will become: `expr = expr '+' expr`

So how will this be reduced to get `VARIABLE '=' expr       { sym[$1] = $3; }` ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Enable [bison's trace facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing) and you can watch it all happening, step by step.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is shifted; `=` is shifted; `3,+,4` are shifted; then `3+4` matches the addition production, which is reduced to `expr`, which then allows the  assignment production to be reduced. You need to remember that *yacc* is a bottom-up parser.

Comment: There are also two reductions of the `expr: INTEGER` rule (immediately after shifting `3` and `4`), which are just simple copies of the value.

Comment: ok got it... one more question - what is the difference between yylval & yytext ?

Comment: @EJP :there is also this Production : expr = VARIALBLE. So while parsing, wouldn't the expression x = 3 + 4 become expr = expr + expr ? If yes, then how will it match to the Production VARIABLE = expr ? since VARIABLE has been reduced already to expr ?

Comment: `yytext` is the buffer the lex scanner is using to recognize tokens.  `yylval` is the attribute value sent by the lex scanner to the yacc parser for the token it is returning.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i tried to give line by line explanation of your **lex rule** section. In next post, i will try to give the explanation of your YACC grammar section.

```
    //----------LEX Rule Section----------  pattern   <->   {co-responding action}
    // yytext :
    // What actualy yytext does is: it acts like a pointer which points the location of current charchter reading on  
    // as i said, this yytext is pointer for lex/flex file . So ,to access  the value of yytext . We need * before it.
    // yylaval:
    // it pass the semantic value of a token from the lexer(lex/flex file or .l file) to the parser(yacc/bison file or .y file)
    // Or you can say this yylval returns value associated token
    // yyerror()
    // when yyparse() is called it automatically invoke yyerror() when any syntax error arise
%% 

[a-z]       {/* Consider a case where user is is giving input as 'f-a' or 'b+c' . As this is calculator programme So we are handling this case by converting these input as ascii value   */
                 yylval = *yytext - 'a'; /* Current value of yytext minus ascii value 'a' is stored into yylval */
                 return VARIABLE;  /* here VARIABLE specified non-terminal for .y file */
             }
[0-9]+      {
                 yylval = atoi(yytext); /* atoi() is a lirary function of stdlib.h . it converts the string argument to an integer value*/ 
                 return INTEGER; /* here also INTEGER specified non-terminal for .y file */
             }

[-+()=*/]   { return *yytext; } /* inside [] bracket, elements are considered as charchter set,if any element matched then fire the action section

[ \t]      {;} /* if any space or tab encounters then here action section is to do nothing */
.          { yyerror("invalid character"); } /* actually . means all charchters except new line */
                                             /* But here we introduced . at the end of rule section,So this . means all other charchters except above specified pattern and except new line */ 
%%
```